# Conveter array comum em array associativo

Tags: php

Preciso transformar esse array:

```
Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Email
                        [value] => xxx@xxx.com
                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Telefone
                        [value] => 22222222222222
                    )

                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Code
                        [value] => D9CI8C
                    )

                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Nome
                        [value] => Igor de Oliveir
                    )

                [4] => Array
                    (
                        [name] => Problema
                        [value] => teste
                    )

            )

    )
```

Em um array assoc, que fique no formato:

```
    array(
   ['email'] = xxxx@xxx.com
   ['telefone'] = 2222222
)
```

e assim por diante, Tentei aplicar um foreach, porem ele me retorna o mesmo array original:

```
$arrayfields = $node['fields'];
    $newarrray = array();
    foreach ($arrayfields as $name => $value) {
      $newarrray[$name] = $value;

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você tiver sempre o vetor com par 'name' e 'value', dá pra fazer mais simplificado:

```
$arrayfields = $node['fields'];
$newarrray = array();
foreach ($arrayfields as $item){
    $newarrray[$item['name']] = $item['value'];
}
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Existem duas formas de fazer isso, a primeira com `array_column()` que extrair uma coluna/chave de um array que no caso vai fazer isso duas vezes, uma para `name` e outra para `value` por fim `array_combine()` cria um novo array onde chaves são o resutado da extração de `name` e os valores a extração de `value`

[Exemplo - idone](https://ideone.com/i0wh2h)

```
<?php

$arr = array(array('name' => 'email', 'value' => 'teste@teste.com'),
             array('name' => 'code', 'value' => 'D9CI8C'),
             array('name' => 'nome', 'value' => 'fulano'),
             array('name' => 'problema', 'value' => 'algo errado')
);

$novo = array_combine(array_column($arr,'name'), array_column($arr,'value'));

print_r($novo);
```

Ou apenas com um foreach:

```
$novo = array();
foreach($arr as $item) $novo[$item['name']] = $item['value'];

print_r($novo);
```

[Exemplo - ideone](https://ideone.com/DlLKDF)

Em ambos os códigos a saída é:

```
Array
(
    [email] => teste@teste.com
    [code] => D9CI8C
    [nome] => fulano
    [problema] => algo errado
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não conseguiu pois tem um `array` dentro do seu primeiro `array` no qual você roda o `foreach`, assim funcionará:

```
<?php

$array_errado = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'email',
        'value' => 'teste@email.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'telefone',
        'value' => '3445-4545'
    ),
    2 => array(
        'name' => 'code',
        'value' => 'D9CI8C'
    )
);

$array_certo = array();

foreach ($array_errado as $sub_array) {
    foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
        $array_certo[$key] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```